# Proper way to access fileshare with docker ubuntu server

Tags: docker, ubuntu, fileshare

I’m learning both Linux(ubuntu) and docker.
I’m so far that my servies is running as it should in my docker container.
The service needs to access a fileshare for data access.
I also want the docker mounts to reside on a fileshare so noting “important” lies on the host itself.

How should I set this up properly?
If would think that for the docker mounts that this should be done on the host?
The file access from the docker however should I set this up via the dockerfile or is it just as fast to set it up on the host and mount it through docker?
There is no security concern as to mount on host in this case.

My next question will probably be how do I mount the share correct?

Regard Lars

Comment: If there is no security concern, mount the share on the host.

Comment: Which is the fastest or "Best practice" ?